# Update custom user model with a form Django

Tags: python, django

I have a **custom user model** I made, I am trying to make a form that will update it when submitted. I have looked at other answers on SO and have tried their solutions, even if my code is almost identical it will not work properly. **I am getting no errors at all** when I run this. The form shouldn't create a new UserAddress, but it should update its field.

models.py

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_address')
    your_address = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, default=' ')

#used in sign up
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_address(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserAddress.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_address(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.user_address.save()
```

forms.py

```
class YourAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ('your_address', )
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def settings(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourAddressForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Awesome, I added it!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not added")
    else:
        form = YourAddressForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'details/settings.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form model is UserAddress, but you are passing `request.user`, which is an instance of User. You should pass the related address object:

```
form = YourAddressForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.user_address)
```

(And the same in the GET block.)